# Что такое extern "C++"?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Знаю, что `extern "C"` используют для отключения декорирования имён, что часто применяется для экспортируемых функций.

А что делает `extern "C++"`?

---

Заголовочный файл `corecrt.h` содержит

```
//-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
//
// C++ Secure Overload Generation Macros
//
//-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
#ifndef RC_INVOKED
    #if defined __cplusplus && _CRT_SECURE_CPP_OVERLOAD_SECURE_NAMES

        #define __DEFINE_CPP_OVERLOAD_SECURE_FUNC_0_0(_ReturnType, _FuncName, _DstType, _Dst)     \
            extern "C++"                                                                          \
            {                                                                                     \
                template <size_t _Size>                                                           \
                inline                                                                            \
                _ReturnType __CRTDECL _FuncName(_DstType (&_Dst)[_Size]) _CRT_SECURE_CPP_NOTHROW  \
                {                                                                                 \
                    return _FuncName(_Dst, _Size);                                                \
                }                                                                                 \
            }
```

Макрос дальше используется в `stdio.h`:

```
__DEFINE_CPP_OVERLOAD_SECURE_FUNC_0_0(
    char*, gets_s,
    char, _Buffer)
```

для объявления функций с массивом фиксированного размера:

[image: gets_s]

Компилятор Visual Studio 2015.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для связи с другими языками программирования в C++ введена спецификация, называемая `linkage specification`.

Из стандарта C++ (7.5 Linkage specifications)

> 1 All function types, function names with external linkage, and
>   variable names with external linkage have a language linkage. [ Note:
>   Some of the properties associated with an entity with language linkage
>   are specific to each implementation and are not described here. For
>   example, a particular language linkage may be associated with a
>   particular form of representing names of objects and functions with
>   external linkage, or with a particular calling convention, etc. —end
>   note ] The default language linkage of all function types, function
>   names, and variable names is C++ language linkage. Two function types
>   with different language linkages are distinct types even if they are
>   otherwise identical.

Стандартом поддерживается два литерала, используемых для связи с другими языками. Это

```
extern "C++"
```

и

```
extern "C"
```

Другие литералы в этой спецификации могут поддерживаться самостоятельно реализациями компиляторов.

Например, могут в программе на языке C++ использоваться имена (например, функции) из языка программирования Fortran. В этом случае эти имена могут предваряться спецификацией

```
extern "FORTRAN"
```

Comment: Зачем указывать `extern "C++"`, если она идёт по умолчанию?

Comment: @Qwertiy Чтобы различать два имени gets_s, одно из которых объявлено, как имеющее языковое связывание "C", а другое - как имеющее языковое связывание "C++".